# Java Generics Comparable | implement compareTo

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree, comparable, compareto

I'm facing a problem with java generics. My plan is to implement a binary search tree (key & value) with generics with total ordering. I started by creating this `KeyValPair` and faced the problem of getting the right compareTo method.

```
public class KeyValPair <V extends Comparable<V>>
        implements Comparable<KeyValPair<V>>{

    private int key;
    private V value;
    private KeyValPair<V> leftchild;
    private KeyValPair<V> rightchild;

    public KeyValPair(int k,V v){
        key=k;
        value=v;
    }

    public Comparable<?> getKey(){
        return key;
    }

    public Comparable<?> getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public void setRightChild(KeyValPair<V> r){
        rightchild=r;
    }

    public KeyValPair<V> getRightChild(KeyValPair<V> r){
        return rightchild;
    }

    public void setLeftChild(KeyValPair<V> l){
        leftchild=l;
    }

    public KeyValPair<V> getLeftChild(KeyValPair<V> l){
        return leftchild;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(KeyValPair<V> toComp) {
        if(this.getValue().compareTo(toComp.getValue())>0){
            return -1;
        }else if(this.getValue().compareTo(toComp.getValue())==0){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

The if sentences in `compareTo` are not acceppted and I think it's because of the fact that I overrode the `compareTo`, but how should I compare generics?

Also tried `Comparable` instead of `K` with same result.

Best Regards

EDIT: What compiler says: Multiple markers at this line - The method compareTo(capture#1-of ?) in the type Comparable is not applicable for the arguments (Comparable) - Line breakpoint:KeyValPair [line: 39] - compareTo(KeyValPair)

EDIT2:

UPDATED CODE:

```
public class KeyValPair{

private int key;
private Comparable<?> value;
private KeyValPair leftchild;
private KeyValPair rightchild;

public KeyValPair(int k,Comparable<?> v){
    key=k;
    value=v;
}

public Comparable<?> getKey(){
    return key;
}

public Comparable<?> getValue(){
    return value;
}

public void setRightChild(KeyValPair r){
    rightchild=r;
}

public KeyValPair getRightChild(KeyValPair r){
    return rightchild;
}

public void setLeftChild(KeyValPair l){
    leftchild=l;
}

public KeyValPair getLeftChild(KeyValPair l){
    return leftchild;
}

}
```

Now i updated the code of the KEYVALPAIR, but if i test it with my BST Class with method adder as example:

```
private void adder(KeyValPair current,KeyValPair toInsert) {
    if(toInsert.getValue().compareTo(current.getValue())>0){
        //dosomething
    }
}
```

it throws:
The method compareTo(capture#2-of ?) in the type Comparable is not applicable for the 
 arguments (Comparable)

SOLUTION:

I solved it by putting KEYVALPAIR as inner class to BST and use V extends Comparable.
Works now, thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "are not accepted?"  What is the compiler telling you, exactly?

Comment: What does "The if sentences in compareTo are not acceppted" mean? I suspect getValue should be returning type V btw.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method compareTo(capture#1-of ?) in the type Comparable<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable 
  for the arguments (Comparable<capture#2-of ?>)
 - Line breakpoint:KeyValPair [line: 39] - compareTo(KeyValPair<V>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to cast key or value to comparable since `V` is required to be comparable already. Doing so just makes it harder to use your class because now you have just a `Comparable` instead of usable values or keys.

```
public int getKey() {
    return key;
}

public V getValue() {
    return value;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(KeyValPair<V> toComp) {
    return -this.getValue().compareTo(toComp.getValue());
}
```

You should also consider to relax the requirement that `V` must implement `Comparable<V>`

```
class KeyValPair<V extends Comparable<? super V>>
```

would allow e.g. classes like `Apple extends Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>` - those can still be ordered if they are comparable to super types.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are required to compare `V` to an other `V` and you don't have the slightest idea about its runtime type.

It can be a `String` or an `Integer` and you obviously don't compare them the same way.

So I think that your `KeyValPair` should not implement `Comparable` since its members (`V` instances) are already doing so: `<V extends Comparable<V>>`.

If you want some comparison you can simply do something like:

```
leftChild.getValue().compareTo(rightChild.getValue());
```

`getValue()` should also return `Comparable<V>`, the wildcard is not necessary.

Comment: ok i deleted the implement and  the  @Override but how can i make a working compareTo method then? If i never typecast i never know how to compare, but the meaning of generics is that they don't have to be typecasted? Should i implement compareTo methods for every type or what do you suggest? thx btw

Comment: The point is that you don't have to know how to compare because the `V` instances will know you just call `compareTo` on them. They are already `Comparable`.

Comment: ok i think i understood, i updated the code (see Question) but now i faced a new problem with the other class BST